# If the Sun had a larger surface temperature how would that affect its appearance to us in the sky?

Tags: visible-light, temperature, thermal-radiation, atmospheric-science, sun

I thought about this when I came across wiens displacement law which says the higher the temperature, the lower the peak wavelength. If the sun was a lot hotter, and its peak wavelength wasn't in the visible part of the EM spectrum. How would this change the suns appearance to us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sun's surface would be hotter,
then - instead of being white - it would look more bluish-white.

Even if it would be much hotter, and the spectral peak would be in far ultra-violet,
then the visible part of the spectrum still would make it look bluish for our eyes.

This graphic from [Wikipedia: Color temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_temperature) visualizes how the color
of a Planckian light source depends on its temperature $T$.

[image: Planckian locus]

Actually there are stars with such high temperatures:
[B-type stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_classification#Class_B) (with $T > 10000 \text{ K}$)
and [O-type stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_classification#Class_O) (with $T > 30000 \text{ K}$).